# If $|f'_n(x)|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ and $\int_0^1f_n(x)dx =0$, then exists a subsequence which converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, arzela-ascoli

> Let $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions such that:
>   $|f'_n(x)|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ and $\int_0^1f_n(x)dx =0$ for every $n\in N$. Prove that exists a subsequence of $(f_n)$ which converges uniformly.

I know that I must apply Arzelá-Ascoli theorem. The problem then comes to show that the sequence $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded and that it is equicontinuous.

What I have noted/done so far:

Since $|f'_n(x)|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$, if $x,y\in [0,1],x\neq y$, then

$$|f_n(y)-f_n(x)|=|\int_x^yf'_n(t)dt |\leq\int_x^y|f'_n(t)|dt\leq\int_x^y\frac{1}{\sqrt t}dt\leq\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt t}dt = K$$

but I can't use this to solve the problem. Any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and every $x,y\in [0,1]$,
$$
|f_n(y) - f_n(x)| \leq \left|
\int_x^y \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\, ds
\right|
= 2 \left| \sqrt{y} - \sqrt{x}\right|
\leq 2 \sqrt{|y-x|},
$$
so that the sequence $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous.

On the other hand, the condition $\int_0^1 f_n = 0$ implies that the sequence is equibounded. Namely, from the mean value theorem, for every $n$ there exists a point $x_n\in [0,1]$ such that $f_n(x_n) = 0$, so that
$$
|f_n(x)| = |f_n(x) - f_n(x_n)| \leq \left| \int_{x_n}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\, ds\right| \leq 2,
\qquad \forall x\in [0,1].
$$

Comment: perfectly noted, thank you